# How to show that a system of even number of Fermion has integer spin?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I am informed that a system of even number of fermions has integer spin. I don't know how to show it with creation and annihilation operators.

Comment: Have you learned about the [addition of angular momentum](https://quantummechanics.ucsd.edu/ph130a/130_notes/node311.html) in quantum mechanics?

Comment: I just read the notes. It is very helpful. Thank you very much.